# Java script function returns "undefined" in NodeJS with mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a function that supposed to return a first_name and I manipulate it in the javascript file. However, the function returns "undefined". The main idea is to retrieve first_name value from mysql table (people) and compare it with a given name. Here is the function that I use:

```
function getFirstname() {
connection.query('SELECT first_name FROM people WHERE id = 14', function(err, rows) {
    if (err) throw err;
    return rows;
   });
}
```

Comment: returns undefined  you mean `getFirstname` or `connection.query`

Comment: getFirstName returns undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are missing a return

```
function getFirstname() {
    return connection.query('SELECT first_name FROM people WHERE id = 14', function(err, rows) {
        if (err) throw err;
        return rows;
    });
}
```

Alternatively, you can do something like this

```
function getFirstname() {
    let results;
    connection.query('SELECT first_name FROM people WHERE id = 14', function(err, rows) {
        if (err) throw err;
        results = rows;
    });
    return results;
}
```

Comment: That's the same code that I use and it has return .

Comment: @Karatay - look again it's not the same. Unless the original code you posted is incorrect. Upvoting as looks to be correct to me.